# Function to get username field of logged in user

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I used to have this function in my func.inc.php but once I moved on a different host, it ceased working and I'm searching for an alternative.

```
function getuserfield($field, $link) {
        $query = $link->prepare("SELECT `$field` FROM `users` WHERE `id`= :session_id");
        if ($query->execute(array(':session_id' => $_SESSION['user_id']['id']))) {
                if ($query_result = $query->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
                        return $query_result;
                }
        }
}
```

I used to call it like this:

```
  $userc = getuserfield('username', $link);

  foreach ($userc as $key) { 
    foreach ($key as $another) {
        $username = $another; 
    } 
  }
```

But on the new host if I have say three users: Bob, Alice, Tom in my database, it would display them all like so: `You're logged in as: BobAliceTom`. I can't find what the problem is because it shouldn't be any php.ini configuration or something.

Comment: You know you are resetting `$username` each iteration of your `foreach`? Use array instead: `$username[] = $another;`.

Comment: The only way that could be happening is if you have duplicate `id` values in the `users` table. Where is the code printing `You're logged in as`?

Comment: Why do you need the inner loop, instead of just `$username = $key['username'];`?

Comment: @Barmar, you are totally correct. It seems I had forgotten to auto increment the ID column. Pardon me.

Comment: Although that doesn't explain how you're seeing all 3 names, when your loop just sets the variable to the last one when it's done. I guess that's not the actual code you're using to display the logged in user, you just put it in there to confuse us some more.

Comment: if you expect only one one zero results you should not do `fetchAll` but `fetch`. And i would add a `LIMIT 1` to your query to ensure that there will only be one or zero results.